# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "stocks" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, heroku

I have been stuck trying to fix this db bug for the better part of a week. Any help is appreciated; looking for any solution, no matter how drastic.

The problem occurred because there was no migration file for a table, "stocks" in my schema. I created the table "stocks" in a different feature branch, and for whatever reason, this migration file didn't make it back to the master branch after merging. So there was no create_stocks migration file, but there were several add_column_to_stocks migration files.

So I tried reordering my migration files and that didn't work, so then I cleaned up my migration files and ran a rake db:migrate:reset, so everything is fine on my production side. If I run a rake db:migrate on my production side, I get no errors, but when I try pushing this to heroku, I get a weird message. It seems to continue to want to migrate a migration file that no longer exists.

Here's the full message:

```
Called from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport- 
4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* 
FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to AddLatestPriceToStocks (20180515064500)
(1.1ms)  BEGIN
== 20180515064500 AddLatestPriceToStocks: migrating 
===========================
-- add_column(:stocks, :latest_price, :decimal)
(1.9ms)  ALTER TABLE "stocks" ADD "latest_price" decimal
(1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations 
canceled:

 PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "stocks" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "stocks" ADD "latest_price" decimal
```

Here are my migration files; notice there is no longer a 20180515064500 migration file, so I have no idea why it's still trying to migrate this to heroku.

```
  up     20171231042756  Create articles
  up     20171231044214  Add description to articles
  up     20180116183526  Create users
  up     20180116191414  Add user to articles
  up     20180116195212  Add password digest to users
  up     20180305082108  Create categories
  up     20180305090315  Create article categories
  up     20180521021514  Create user stocks
  up     20180530032220  Create stocks
```

Here is my local production schema:

```
create_table "article_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "article_id"
t.integer "category_id"
end

create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "description"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "stocks", force: :cascade do |t|
t.decimal  "latest_price"
t.string   "company_name"
t.datetime "latest_time"
t.integer  "latest_update"
end

create_table "user_stocks", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "stock_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "user_stocks", ["stock_id"], name: "index_user_stocks_on_stock_id"
add_index "user_stocks", ["user_id"], name: "index_user_stocks_on_user_id"

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "username"
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "password_digest"
end
```

And here is my Heroku schema:

```
create_table "article_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "article_id"
t.integer "category_id"
end

create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "description"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "username"
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "password_digest"
end

end
```

Not sure if I've made the problem worse. I'm looking for any solution at this point, no matter how drastic. Any help is appreciated and hopefully this is enough information.

Comment: so do you ultimately want the table `stocks` on heroku and migrations on top of it(like add latest stock prices) or not?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should remove the entry "20180515064500" from the table named "schema_migrations" (`ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration.all` if you want to access them from a Rails console). =

Comment: yup. that should solve it. On heroku, get into your db console, and `delete from schema_migrations where version = 20180515064500` 20180515064500(stock table is modified) is before 20180530032220(stocks table is created) which is reporting this error.

Comment: So I can't figure out where to find these migrations and delete them. If I get into my heroku psql console and try to delete that specific migration, it comes back with the result DELETE 0, which means it's deleted nothing. 

But if I do a heroku rake db:migrate:status, I can see all the problematic migration files that need to be deleted. Where would I go to delete those migration files? Where are those old migration files being stored?